# how do i hide a preloader in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to hide ajax preloader on some of the pages in my code. how can i do that. Ur suggestions will be helpful.

Code is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
    //alert("Loader-->"+n[1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     $('#loading').hide();
           if(n[1]!=undefined){
            /*jQuery('#loading').fadeOut(10, function() {
             jQuery('body').css('overflow','visible');
             jQuery(this).remove();
        });*/

        /*$('#loading').ajaxStop(function(){
                $(this).hide();
        });*/
        //$('#loading').hide();
        }
        //$('#loading').hide();
    });
```

In this code snippet i have pasted that code also on which i have worked on but didnt work.

html code

```
        <div align="center">

            <div align="center" id="container"> 
                <div id="logo" align="center" ><img src="images/Updated_1logo.png" border="0" alt="STIHL logo"/> </div>

                <div style="clear:both"></div>

                <div id='divMain'>
                    <table width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%" >&nbsp;</td>

                            <td style="position:absolute;left:60%;top: 50%;">
                                <img src="images/gray_image_002.png"  border="0" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>          

                    <div  id="circle1"> 
                        <div id="circle12"><br/> <br/><b>Employee Benefits</b></div> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="circle" id="circle2">
                        <div id="circle22"><br/> <b>Expectations</b></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="circle" id="circle3">
                        <div id="circle32"><br/> <b>Manufacturing <br/>Operations Safety</b></div> 
                    </div> 
                </div>
</div>
</div>
```

dont go with the closing tags

Comment: $(function() { $('div#loading').hide(); });

Comment: this is not relative to HTML5 at all, i edit your question

Comment: thanks for the reply but this is also not working ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code works fine 4 me

```
<script>
var js = '<html><div id="loading"><img id="loading-image" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading...  /></div></html>'
if (window.location.href.indexOf("divModule") != -1) {
    //alert('here'+window.location.href.indexOf("divModule"))
    $("body").prepend(js);
}               
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, to hide ajax preloader on some of the pages like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#loading').show();
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#loading').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but not working :(. I just need in the fucntion where i have applied condition "if(n[1]!=undefined){}" in this i am getting a div name which particular is loading on that page. On that particular i wanted to hide. i tried this code but not working. still i can see loader for a fractions of secs. can i destroy or exit from the preloader for particular div?

Comment: at my end it works fine when i tried with above commented codes also. but i can see the loader for fractions of sec when i am giving my link to any other person for looking the same

Comment: Palash Mondal gives you a global solution which works. I'm still wondering what you are exactly looking for? Just show preloader for a specific ajax request?

Comment: This should work as soon as any ajax load function is called. The above code listen to ajax start/stop events and show/hide loading animation. Have you tried calling your code inside the `$(document).ready` not inside the `$(window).load`?

Comment: i have added some code which i have written in body.. is der any prob?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your HTML markup. Maybe there's some issue where you are making the ajax call. Could you post that too..

Comment: i pasted all what i have used for that